# Sesamanuel and ifluatex

Tags: errors

I usually work with sesamanuel to produce texts for my math classes, 
but in the new update of MacTeX, an error arises.

! Package ifluatex Error: Name clash, \ifluatex is already defined.See the ifluatex package documentation for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... }

And I can not understand what is happening. Would someone know what to do in this case so he can use sesamanuel again? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you provide a small example document that shows this error? You can add it to your question by pressing the `edit` button below the post.

Comment: Complain to the class maintainer. A class that loads so many other packages should use the standard interfaces for ifluatex and not create its own if command.

Answer (score 5):

It would be better if the class was fixed, but meanwhile you can do

```
\RequirePackage{ifluatex}
\let\ifluatex\relax
\documentclass{sesamanuel}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. I hope that in the next update we do not need to use this trick

Comment: @PepeRosell you could report it to the class author

Answer (score 3):

The documentation of the class states

> On chargera le minimum d’extensions dans la classe afin de limiter les problèmes de compatibilités avec les différentes distributions TeX (distributions et versions de ces distributions). On aurait pu choisir de charger les extensions `ifpdf`, `ifluatex` et `ifxetex` pour tester le mode de compilation et agir en conséquence mais on n’a pas besoin de ce luxe : comme on est en tout début de classe, on peut utiliser des méthodes légèrement moins solides que celles fournies dans ces extensions mais très largement suffisantes ici.

> We’ll load a bare minimum of packages in the class in order to limit problems of compatibility among different TeX distributions (distributions and versions thereof). We could have chosen to load the packages `ifpdf`, `ifluatex` and `ifxetex` in order to test the engine and act on consequence, but we don’t need such a luxury: as we’re at the very start of the class, we can employ methods slightly less robust than those provided by those packages, but largely sufficient here.

This statement is a bit weird:

- the package `ifxetex` has been [unchanged since 2010](http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty?view=log)
- the package `ifluatex` was [modified in 2016 from its earlier version of 2011](http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty?view=log) but the change consisted in [updating the version number](http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty?r1=22124&r2=41247) (because it belongs to a larger bundle)
- the package `ifpdf` has a slightly different status and indeed it underwent some major changes between TeX Live 2015 and 2016, mainly to include better LuaTeX support, but has been basically stable since 2011 as well.

The class code contradicts the initial statement later on, when it loads `etex`, `geometry`, `crop`, `ifmtarg`,  `mathtools`, `amssymb`, `longtable`, `tabularx`, `multirow`, `xcolor` (with `table` option), `pst-all`, `pstricks-add`, `fancyhdr`, `fancyvrb`, `multicol`, `babel` (with `french` option), `numprint`, besides some font packages. This doesn't qualify as “bare minimum” to my eyes.

The “culprit” is `pst-all`, that in turn loads `pst-calculate` and this one now loads `siunitx`, which requires `ifluatex`.

The final effect is that “limiting problems of compatibility” and to not load *standard* packages, basically unchanged for more than three years before the release of `sesamanuel`, actually *creates* them.

By the way, the 2015-01-01 release of LaTeX (which predates the release of `sesamanuel`) made `etex` no longer necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your great report. I am happy to learn from smart people who make me improve in LateX knowledge.